# Tricky logical XOR for nullable values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have 2 nullable `CHAR` columns and I need to check if **only one of them** is null.

Doing

```
(a IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL) OR (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL)
```

is boring. And I would like to avoid creating custom functions for that.

I was thinking about something like

```
COALESCE(a, 1) + COALESCE(b, 1) = 1
```

but as long as `a` is `char` - it causes operand type error.

So, any *tricky* solutions?

Comment: How about `COALESCE(a,b)=COALESCE(b,a)` :)  Will yield incorrect value if `a=b`. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9c33b/1

Comment: @mellamokb: deserves an upvote, though `select coalesce(null, null) = coalesce(null, null)` returns not boolean (which could lead to errors in some cases)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you mean *exactly* one is NULL (which matches your existing logic), then:

```
a is null != b is null
```

Comment: Surprised it was so simple :-)

Comment: @zerkms: I had to double check it, hence the quick delete/undelete :)

Comment: @mu is too short: yep, I've seen it deleted and wondered why you did it, while thinking about possible pitfalls

Comment: @zerkms: I got stuck second guessing myself and had to build the truth table to make sure I wasn't being a [type-1 or type-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors) idiot.

Answer (score 8):

And if you're using PostgreSQL don't forget the parentheses...

```
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ADD CHECK ((key1 IS NULL) <> (key2 IS NULL));
```

(I spent almost 10 minutes trying to understand what was wrong with my CHECK.)